# get the value of hidden parameter present in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div whose id is "mainDiv" and a hidden field is in this div whose class name is "myHiddenField". Now I want to get the value of that hidden parameter using jquery.

I have tried:

```
$("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").val()
```

and

```
$("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").attr('value')
```

Comment: i used $("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").val() and also used $("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").attr('value')

Comment: ur first try should work.. can you post the code? in jsfiddle perhaps

Answer (score 2):

`$("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").val()`

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straightforward combination of [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var value = $("#mainDiv").find(".myHiddenField").val();
```

Or you can omit the `find` part by using a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) instead:

```
var value = $("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").val();
```

Comment: the OP said class of `myHiddenField`

Comment: @ManseUK: Thanks; originally it just said "name," not "class name."

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $('#mainDiv > .myHiddenField').val();
```

Comment: Sorry @f0x, I misread the question. I clearly thought the field had the id, not was contained within it. I blame a poorly worded question, and if that fails, my sanity.

Comment: no worries, your explanation happens more than often ;) had a good laugh. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of id- and class-selector, so that you select the element of class `myFiddenField` that has an ancestor with id `mainDiv`. When you have selected the proper element, you use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of that element.

Something like this:

```
$("#mainDiv .myHiddenField").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML part :

```
<div class="myHiddenField">hidden value</div>
```

JS Part:

```
var x = $('.myHiddenField').html();
```

Here x gives the value of your hidden div.